# How to read SD Card with J2ME Code?

Tags: java-me, sd-card

```
String initDir = System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.photos");
```

when i use it the way above, I just read the directory images in phone memory. How that can read image files contained on the SDCard?

some ways I have ever tried as follows but can't to read SDCard:

```
String initDir = System.getProperty("file:///SDCard/");
String initDir = System.getProperty("file:////");
```

Is there any other way to read SD Card Details ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution lies in the [FileConnection Optional Package](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/), this package enables J2ME-based applications to create, **read**, and write files and directories located on mobile devices and external memory cards. More about how to do this is available from the given link.

Comment: +1 for @Sanjay, you can find small sample of FileConnection on my blog http://tinyurl.com/qsn43f (if admin feels that this is advertising please kindly delete it)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read as `E:` , SDCard is formed as `E:` in Nokia Mobile, while `C:` is phone memory.

Comment: How portable is that across phones?